# /proc file system hangs my system

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

Hello I am new to kernel space programming and I came to learn about the proc file system.

I have written a module which creates a proc file while registering

And I remove that while unregistering the module.
But if I dont remove that file using the remove_proc_entry() and unregister my module then the system hangs after some time

Why this is so?

The code is

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/proc_fs.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>

int myopen(struct inode *, struct file *);
ssize_t myread(struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);

int myopen(struct inode *p, struct file *q)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "I am in myopen\n");
        return 0;
}

ssize_t myread(struct file *p, char __user *q, size_t r, loff_t *s)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "I am in myread\n");
        return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations fs={
        .open=myopen,
        .read=myread
};

int start(void)
{
        proc_create("myprocfile", 0, NULL, &fs);
        return 0;
}

void stop(void)
{
        //remove_proc_entry("myprocfile", NULL);
        /*
          If I uncomment the above line
          then everything works fine
        */
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(stop);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file is accessed, `file_operations` structure is read, and futher actions depends on pointers, stored in this structure.

If you do not delete file upon module exiting, **file remains accessible**. But **`file_operations` structure**, associated with it, **is freed**. So, any access to the file after module unloading cause reading the data, which has been freed. This trigger error in accessing memory.

That's why it is critical for kernel module to remove all objects it creates before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fine explanation.....But I dont understand after I unregister the module who does the file operations. I have not written any user space code for this...Then who does the operations on the freed memory?

Comment: It can be, e.g., system deamon, which checks files periodically. In any case having file associated with freed operations structure is bad.

Comment: When I try to unregister the module it gives me a message on the terminal "killed"...I cant figure out which process is killed here